# Como aplicar negrito em um trecho de texto de um documento PDF criado manualmente?

Tags: pdf

Estou desenvolvendo um módulo responsável por gerar e exportar documentos em PDF (Relatórios). Como não achei nenhuma solução *third party free*, então estou utilizando uma biblioteca simples em VB, que coloca o cabeçalho do documento e define algumas configurações básicas como fonte, tamanho do papel e tudo mais.

De resto, estou fazendo na mão.

Gostaria de saber, como se aplica o negrito em apenas uma trecho de texto do documento PDF. Eu reparei que as pessoas criam uma espécie de objeto do tipo fonte no código "PDF/PostScript" entretanto ele é amarrado a outros objetos e não sei como cria-lo.

Veja a [documentação da classe de PDF usada](http://mnicolato.altervista.org/vb/vb2pdf.htm).

Comment: Fale qual biblioteca está utilizando, talvez alguém a conheça e consiga te ajudar.

Comment: Estou utilizando na verdade uma classe chamada VBPDF que achei google afora. Ela é bem simples, na verdade só a utilizo porque ela adiciona automaticamente os códigos de cabeçalho de um documento PDF.

Comment: Coloque o link da biblioteca na pergunta, assim as pessoas podem saber do que se trata.

Answer (score 2):

### EDIÇÃO:

Como foi explicado nos comentários o link da [classe VB2PDF](http://mnicolato.altervista.org/vb/vb2pdf.htm), mas vou deixar o exemplo da biblioteca [vbPDF](http://www.luigimicco.altervista.org/doku.php/en/home) caso alguém tenha uma dúvida com ela.

### Como colocar em negrito no VB2PDF:

Como pode ser visto na própria documentação do site, os objetos dessa classe contém uma propriedade `FontType` que adequa a formatação do texto, para deixar em negrito basta fazer como no exemplo:

```vb
Dim objPDF As New VB2PDF
With objPDF
 .PaperSize = pdfA4
 .FileName = "c:\temp\test.pdf"
 .StartPDF
 .WritePDF "Hello world !", True, .pdfBold
 .EndPDF
End With
```

Esse exemplo deve criar um texto Hello world ! com negrito.

### Como colocar em negrito no vbPDF:

É possível alterar os estilos de fonte como pode ser [visto aqui](http://www.luigimicco.altervista.org/doku.php/en/doc/guide/setfont), basta usar o método `setFont`, por [exemplo](http://www.luigimicco.altervista.org/doku.php/en/doc/sample/helloworld):

```vb
Dim clPDF As New vbPDF 
With clPDF
  .BeginDoc
  If .ErrNumber = 0 then
    .BeginPage
    ' Aqui seta as opções de fonte (Família, tamanho, estilo)'
    .SetFont "Times", 24, .pdfBold
    .DrawText 1, 15, "Hello world !"
    .EndDoc
  End If
End With
```

Alterei um pouco o exemplo que passei no link, para incluir o negrito.

Comment: Felipe, Grato pela ajuda. Entretanto, eu atualizei o post com o link da classe correta. Esta classe que vc postou, tem o nome parecido com a que estou utilizando no momento.

Comment: Nesse mesmo link que você mandou, existe uma propriedade `FontType`, o qual tem constantes simbólicas. Uma delas é `pdfBold`, o que deve deixar a font em negrito.

Comment: Adicionei como fazer no VB2PDF.

Comment: Grato, consegui dar um jeito! :D

Answer (score 0):

Achei esta página, que é a documentação de uma biblioteca chamada VBPDF, está falando sobre como usar negrito, itálico e tal...

Veja: [VBPDF set font](http://www.luigimicco.altervista.org/doku.php/en/doc/guide/setfont)

Comment: Eu ja usei esta API, ela é voltada para geração de documentos em PDF. Infelizmente, estas definições só funcionam no contexto dessa API, que nada tem a ver com a emissao de documentos XLS. Entretanto, agradeço a força... grato!